# Does C99 permit universal character names in identifiers?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c99

From §6.4.2 of the WG14/N1124 draft of the C99 spec, "Identifiers":

> ```
> identifier:  
>        identifier-nondigit  
>        identifier identifier-nondigit  
>        identifier digit
>
> identifier-nondigit:  
>        nondigit  
>        universal-character-name  
>        other implementation-defined characters
> ```

And §6.4.3, "Universal character names":

> ```
> universal-character-name:
>        \u hex-quad
>        \U hex-quad hex-quad
> ```

This seems to suggest that an identifier like `foo\u00AAbar` is valid according to the grammar.  I can't find anything in the semantics that would suggest otherwise.  Yet GCC rejects such an identifier without even trying to parse it:

```
<stdin>:2: error: stray ‘\’ in program
<stdin>:2: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘u00AAbar’
<stdin>:2: error: ‘u00AAbar’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Is this an oversight in GCC, the C99 standard, or my reasoning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

None of those three. It's simply a long-standing unimplemented (or rather, only partially implemented) feature. It's recently been completed, and will be available in GCC 5. Prior to that version, you can use the `-fextended-identifiers` command-line option, but there are some cases that it got wrong that led to it not being enabled by default.

You can see this listed on [Status of C99 features in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html).